# PowerShell or batch script to delete with exclusions

Tags: script, automation, powershell, batch-file

What's a good way to delete everything below a certain path, supplying a list of exclusions?

E.g.

```
C:\
    MyFolder
        MyApp
        MyConfig
        MyWorld
        MyEverything
        MyBankDetails
```

How to delete `C:\MyFolder\*.*` leaving behind `MyBankDetails` such that the folder structure resembles:

```
C:\
    MyFolder
        MyBankDetails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using Powershell:

```
get-childitem C:\Myfolder\ -exclude "MyBankDetails" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

It'll recurse through `C:\Myfolder` and delete everything **except** folder `MyBankDetails`. You can add exclusions, both folders and files, as you wish. For example:

```
... -exclude "MyBankDetails","AnOtherFolder","File.txt",*.someFileExtension ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the answer above: *-Exclude* key works differently since 5.0 version. The above-mentioned code will remove everything except the folder *MyBankDetails* itself, contents will be erased.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159605)